# Зачем alignParentStart в RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

Зачем alignParentStart в RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если атрибут alignParentStart выставлен для объекта внутри RelativeLayout, то этот объект левым краем будет прижат к левому краю RelativeLayout изнутри RelativeLayout. используется слово start, а не left - это разные значения, если выбрано направление справа-на-лево. Например для арабской локализации alignParentStart притянет объект к правому краю 
Вот полезная ссылка: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection